# A Relaxing Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> My prefix is a rotation.
>
> My suffix is a stiff bristle.
>
> My infix is holding a kitten.
>
> Ah, what's my name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a small stretch,  I say a

> yawn

My prefix is a rotation.

> yaw - the rotation of an aircraft or vessel about its vertical axis.

My suffix is a stiff bristle.

> awn  - the bristle of a grass (credit earlier answers).

My infix is holding a kitten.

> aw - that's a cute kittie :)

Comment: You've got it! I'll award the checkmark in a little bit.

Comment: Hah! Nice one :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are

> **COUNTERDRAWN**

because

> (prefix) **counter**-rotation is a kind of rotation
>  (suffix) **awn** is a bristle
>  (infix) **dr** might be a veterinarian

Not really finding a better candidate infix than that, alas.

Comment: Will post a hint soon. Definitely on the right track with one of your fixes.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what @Rubio said:

> I agree in the suffix being **awn**, can't really think of anything else, if you try to find words ending with awn that makes very hard to find any infix different to **dr**.

But

> I can't really agree on **counter** so I'll try something different and say **over**. I'd like to say something like **cos**, **sin**, **x**, **y** but can't find anything with that.

So here's my shot:

> **Overdrawn**

Answer (score 2):

Here's my shot

---

Prefix -

> could be left or right ( or clock/anti)

Infix -

> hand or lap

Suffix -

> awn or seta

So here goes

---

Word -

> Right/Left-hand-awn
>
>  Other groups can be made with different combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mike! It appears that your final solution is not a conventional word.